# Personalize the error view in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Asp.net mvc4 application, in which I would like to personalize the exception page

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml" ></customErrors>
```

the Error page :

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Erreur";
}
<p>Take it easy</p>
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1 class="error">Erreur.</h1>
    <h2 class="error">Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de la requête.</h2>
    
</hgroup>
```

When an exception is thrown, I get a different view :

[image: view]

What is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the error URL to point to the **url** of your error page. Not to the .cshtml as you have it. If your error page's action method (which returns the view defined in Error.cshtml) is "CustomError" and is located in "ErrorController", then you would put the following:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error/CustomError" >
</customErrors>
```

Comment: if i didn't put `defaultRedirect` attribute. what is the default error view ? is it ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml ?

Comment: You never point to a view file in ASP.NET MVC. You define a URL which maps (via the routes defined in your global.asax) to an action method declared in a controller in your application. You therefore need to define a controller and action method which will return the view file containing your error page code. This is getting a bit beyond the scope of the question, but if you don't understand what I'm talking about then you should take some time to read up on how ASP.NET MVC works, because it is conceptually different from what you are probably used to working with.